# What's the difference between svn copy and svn merge for creating a branch?

Tags: svn, branch, svn-merge, svn-copy

What's the difference between `svn copy` and `svn merge` when creating a branch in SVN?

Comment: Read the documentation: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/

Answer (score 2):

Main difference when creating a branch in SVN is:

`svn merge` is not usable for creating branch because it isn't able to do it